# Use overridden method from subclass

Tags: java, inheritance

I have a class `A`:

```
private static class A 
{
  public void foo() 
  {
    Sub sub = new Sub();
    sub.bar();
  }

  protected class Sub 
  {
    protected void bar() 
    {
      System.out.println("bar from A");
    }
  }
}
```

And I want to extend it to slightly modify `bar()` in its subclass `Sub`.

```
private static class B extends A 
{
  protected class Sub extends A.Sub 
  {
    @Override
    protected void bar() 
    {
      System.out.println("bar from B");
    }
  }
}
```

If I try to call it now

```
B b = new B();
b.foo();
```

I get *bar from A*, but I need *bar from B*.

I could solve the problem overriding `foo()`, too. But `foo()` is a huge method and I'd get redundant code if I'd simply copy it. I can not split it into multiple smaller ones.

Is there a way calling the new `bar()` without overriding `foo()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `A.foo()` you are creating an instance of `A.Sub`. That's why `bar()` of `A.Sub` is called, and not `bar()` of `B.Sub`.

One possible solution is to replace

`Sub sub = new Sub();`

with :

`Sub sub = getSub();`

Then in A:

```
protected Sub getSub()
{
    return new Sub();
}
```

And in B:

```
@Override
protected Sub getSub()
{
    return new Sub();
}
```

An instance of `B` would produce an instance of `B.Sub` while an instance of `A` would produce an instance of `A.Sub`.

Answer (score 1):

You are struggling with a rather awkward concept of the Java language which is [called shadowing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4). You know that by `B extends A`, you would overrride all non-private instance methods of `A` that are also defined in `B`. In contrast, you probably know that fields are not overridden. If you define a field with the same name in both `A` and `B`, there exist two fields where the subclass field in `B` *shadows* the field in the super class in `A` without *replacing* its use in `A`.

The same is true for inner classes. This implies that `A.Sub` and `B.Sub` are two different classes just as two (hypothetical) fields `A.foo` and `B.foo` would be distinct. `A.Sub` is merely shadowed by `B.Sub`. Therefore, calling `new Sub()` will create an instance of `A.Sub` when this call is defined within `A` but creates an instance of `B.Sub` when defined within `B`. In order to emulate polymorphism, you need to somehow get a method call involved in order to trigger Java's dynamic dispatch. There are two ways to do that:

1. Define a factory method which you can override to create the desired instance:

   ```
   class A {
      class Sub { void doSomething() { 
        System.out.println("A.Sub"); } 
      }
      Sub make() { return new Sub(); } // Returns B.Sub
   }
   class B extends A {
      class Sub extends A.Sub { // Shadows A.Sub
        void doSomething() { System.out.println("B.Sub"); 
      }
      @Override
      Sub make() { return new Sub(); } // Returns B.Sub, also when called within A
   }
   ```
2. Make the `A.Sub` to `B.Sub` hierarchy polymorphic:

   ```
   class A {
      class Sub { 
        void invoke() { doSomething(); } // Invokes outer method virtually
      }
      void doSomething() { System.out.println("A"); }
   }
   class B extends A {
      class Sub extends A.Sub { }  // Shadows A.Sub
      @Override
      void doSomething() { System.out.println("B"); }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject the `Sub` in the object to achieve that. If you let it to be in the class `A` constructor, it only has visibility to `A.Sub`.

Then, make a constructor for `A` that accepts an `A.Sub` and subclasses:

```
public A(Sub sub) {
  this.sub = sub;
}
```